# React.js setState bad call Warning. { NavLink }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I called a function inside the style attribute.

I want to change a state value based on which `NavLink` is active,
So I made the callback function inside the style attribute because the style callback function has a default parameter that checks if the `NavLink` is active or not.

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  style={({ isActive }) => {
    if (isActive) {
      setActive("Home");
    }
  }}
>
  <span className={`icon `}>
    {active === "Home" ? <HouseDoorFill /> : <HouseDoor />}
  </span>
  <span className="title">Home</span>
</NavLink>
```

That is the warning I get.

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW7fb.jpg)
[Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72TkU.jpg)

I want to know if this warning is critical or not, and how can I solve this issue.

Comment: [Please post code/etc as formatted text, not links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) FWIW a shot of a file name and line number isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that fact that you are enqueueing a state update as an unintentional side-effect during the render cycle. The `style` prop should be returning a `React.CSSProperties` style object though when used. You don't need any state here though as you can use a `children` render function that receives the `isActive` prop.

Example:

```
<NavLink to="/">
  {({ isActive }) => (
    <>
      <span className="icon">
        {isActive ? <HouseDoorFill /> : <HouseDoor />}
      </span>
      <span className="title">Home</span>
    </>
  )}
</NavLink>
```

If you must keep the `active` state then use an `onClick` handler to issue the effect of updating the React state.

```
<NavLink
  to="/"
  onClick={() => setActive("Home")}
>
  <span className="icon">
    {active === "Home" ? <HouseDoorFill /> : <HouseDoor />}
  </span>
  <span className="title">Home</span>
</NavLink>
```

See the [`NavLink` documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) for more detail.